# Preloader com Materialize

Tags: javascript, ajax, materialize

Estou fazendo uma requisição via ajax:

```
$(function () {
    $('#loader').hide();
    $('#formSend').on('submit', function (e) {      
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'proc_pedidos.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
          $('#result_produtos').html(result);
          $('#loader').show();
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Antes do envio do formulário deixo setado `$('#loader').hide();`, aciono ele ao submeter o formulário e após o envio, na página da requisição trago um script:

```
<script>
    $('#loader').hide();
</script>
```

Porém isto não está funcionando. O preloader carrega, mas na volta o script não o esconde.

Comment: Não entendi mt bem o que você tentou fazer... Não é que não está funcionando, é a maneira como você usou, você colocou pra exibir o loader no success do ajax, ai como a requisição ocorre certa ele vai exibir o loader segundo seu código, então no lugar do `show()` coloca `hide()` e vice-versa, ou caso ache melhor use o `beforeSend: $('loader').show()`, e dentro do do `success` coloca `$('loader').hide()`

Comment: @MaxRogério, o que estou tentando é que, ao enviar o formulário, seja acionado o preloader e após a chegada dos dados na página ele desapareça. Por isso, ao submeter o formulário seto como `$('loader').show()` e no arquivo que processa no banco e retorna para a página onde está o formulário coloco `$('loader').hide()`, mas isso não funciona...

Comment: Então ao submeter o formulário, ele vai processar o `ajax`, e você adiciona o `beforeSend : $('#loader').show()`, que vai abrir o loader no momento da requisição, no `success` você manda esconder o `loading`, pois você já tem o callback da função, ou seja, sua requisição ja foi processada e no `success` você pega os dados do callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta assim:

Exibe o seu loader com o `beforeSend:` e remove ele como o `complete:`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'proc_pedidos.php',
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
       $('#result_produtos').html(result);
    },
    beforeSend: function(){

      $('#loader').show();
    },
    complete: function(){
       $('#loader').hide();
    }
  });
```